# Affix: how to show always icon when second navbar goes on first navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, affix

I have 2 navbars: the first is fixed at the top of page, the second navbar is after header and image.

When I scroll down the page I would like second navbar goes on first navbar (and this works now) but the icon's world (blue) is the problem, I would like to show always the icon with second navbar when I scroll, but now second navbar goes above icon too.

**HTML**

```
<div id="usermenu" class="usermenu" role="navigation">

 <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="brand pull-left">
         <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home g-2x"></span></a>
</div>

<div class="pull-right">     
            <div class="btn-group">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">Login</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn">Register</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="header" class="header clearfix">
        <div class="logo col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-ph-6">
            <a href="#"><img src="http://gimepix.com/img/300-100-animals-003" alt="" title=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>     


<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="wrapper topbar">

    <nav id="nav" class="mainmenu clearfix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
        <ul class="menu sf-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Testing &amp; Testing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Show &amp; Tell</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Testing Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bla Bla Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">I don't know</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other other</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

.. content page ..
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
background-color: #F4F4F4;
}  

.affix {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 5;
}

#header, #usermenu {
width: 100%;
}

.header {
background: #FFF;
padding: 0em 1em;
color: #FFF;
padding-top: 3em;
}

.usermenu {
background-color: #2B2E29;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 5;
}

.wrapper {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1160px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.brand {
padding: .5em;
font-size: 1em;
background: #347AB7;
margin-right: 5px;
}

.brand .glyphicon, .g-2x {
font-size: 24px;
color: #FFF;
}

#usermenu .navbar-btn {
margin-top: 4px;
margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.userpanel .btn {
padding-left: 1em;
}

.btn {
border-radius: 2px;
}

.mainmenu {
background-color: #2B2E29;
}

.brand .glyphicon, .g-2x {
font-size: 24px;
color: #FFF;
}

ul.menu {
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

.menu li:first-of-type {
text-align: left;
}
.menu li {
list-style-type: none;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-align: center;
}

.menu li a {
color: #FFF;
}
.menu a, menu a:hover {
color: #FFF;
display: block;
padding: .75em .75em;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I use Bootstrap 3.3.5.

I have added z-index: 5; in CSS for Affix, in this way the second bar goes on first navbar, but I don't know how to put second bar to right of icon of world (like a menu button).

I have trying adding percentual to affix CSS, like:

```
.affix {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 5;
left: 17%;
}
```

but in this way on different screens I have different second bar on first navbar :( I don't know how to explain well, sorry..

I would like only second bar on first nav and button visible on all different breakpoints.

How can I fix it? Thanks

Here the layout: http://www.bootply.com/kl8HHLLBPy

Comment: You need to provide your code in the body of your code. I'm also not sure what language you're using, since you have no language tags.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my topic